# How can I execute commands on startup in awesome?

Tags: boot, awesome-wm

I want to execute some commands after login if awesome-windowmanager starts. How can I add startup-commands to the awesome-config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [ArchLinux wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome3#Autorun_programs) you should just need to add the following to your `rc.lua`:

```
-- Autorun programs
autorun = true
autorunApps = 
{ 
   "swiftfox",
   "mutt",
   "consonance",
   "linux-fetion",
   "weechat-curses",
}
if autorun then
   for app = 1, #autorunApps do
       awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app])
   end
end
```

The wiki also show a couple of other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: What happens when you reload awesome? Is autorun set to false later in the config?

Comment: @Ikraav's point is important.

Comment: you can't actually detect this, even when abusing the globals table like it's done by accident in the example above. awesome reload wipes the lua vm. do something like running "pgrep firefox || firefox" for example instead.

Comment: or actually do it like the wiki suggests, since it seems to have been fixed (and the broken code above removed)

Answer (score 9):

I am going with [dex](https://github.com/jceb/dex), so far.

```
$ cat /etc/X11/Sessions/awesome 
#!/bin/sh
# Awesome Xsession starter, based on Xsession shipped by x11-apps/xinit-1.0.5-r1
...
zenity --title "Autostart" --timeout=30 --question --text="Launch autostart items?" && dex -a
exec ck-launch-session /usr/bin/awesome
```

Let's have some autostart items too then:

```
$ ls -1 ~/.config/autostart/
gol.desktop
KeePass 2.desktop
skype-skype.desktop
tomboy.desktop
wpa_gui-wpa_supplicant.desktop
xterm-logs.desktop
```

Example autostart item:

```
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/gol.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Growl For Linux
Comment=Growl Desktop Notification System For Linux
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
Exec=/usr/bin/gol
Icon=/usr/share/growl-for-linux/data/icon.png
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.18
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Awesome wiki suggests](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Autostart#PID_way) this way that will work when reloading Awesome.

Put this in runonce.lua

```
-- @author Peter J. Kranz (Absurd-Mind, peter@myref.net)
-- Any questions, criticism or praise just drop me an email

local M = {}

-- get the current Pid of awesome
local function getCurrentPid()
    -- get awesome pid from pgrep
    local fpid = io.popen("pgrep -u " .. os.getenv("USER") .. " -o awesome")
    local pid = fpid:read("*n")
    fpid:close()

    -- sanity check
    if pid == nil then
        return -1
    end

    return pid
end

local function getOldPid(filename)
    -- open file
    local pidFile = io.open(filename)
    if pidFile == nil then
        return -1
    end

    -- read number
    local pid = pidFile:read("*n")
    pidFile:close()

    -- sanity check
    if pid <= 0 then
        return -1
    end

    return pid;
end

local function writePid(filename, pid)
    local pidFile = io.open(filename, "w+")
    pidFile:write(pid)
    pidFile:close()
end

local function shallExecute(oldPid, newPid)
    -- simple check if equivalent
    if oldPid == newPid then
        return false
    end

    return true
end

local function getPidFile()
    local host = io.lines("/proc/sys/kernel/hostname")()
    return awful.util.getdir("cache") .. "/awesome." .. host .. ".pid"
end

-- run Once per real awesome start (config reload works)
-- does not cover "pkill awesome && awesome"
function M.run(shellCommand)
    -- check and Execute
    if shallExecute(M.oldPid, M.currentPid) then
        awful.util.spawn_with_shell(shellCommand)
    end
end

M.pidFile = getPidFile()
M.oldPid = getOldPid(M.pidFile)
M.currentPid = getCurrentPid()
writePid(M.pidFile, M.currentPid)

return M
```

Use it this way:

```
local r = require("runonce")

r.run("urxvtd -q -o -f")
r.run("urxvtc")
r.run("urxvtc")
r.run("wmname LG3D")
```

Answer (score 1):

### ArchWiki Approach

For newer users, in the ArchWiki you can find that you need to:

1. create `~/.config/awesome/autorun.sh` and add

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function run {
  if ! pgrep -f $1 ;
  then
    $@&
  fi
}
```

`run` checks with the process grep (so you don't re execute the process), and puts the bins straight into the background.

In the `~/.config/awesome.rc.lua` tell it to spawn that file with the shell (bash or whichever you set). You do it like so (last line in file):

```
awful.spawn.with_shell("~/.config/awesome/autorun.sh")
```

---

### Simpler Approach

Now for me, with many arguments the pgrep was a bit picky. So I wrote a simpler, good for my use at least, script. This is my `autorun.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

feh --bg-scale $(ls ${HOME}/wallpaper/*.png|shuf -n1) &
nm-applet &
```